# Specifying version when using extra latex packages with org mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

Somewhere long ago I read I could use additional latex packages in org-mode using:

```
(setq org-latex-packages-alist '())
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "color" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "physics" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "mathtools" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "xfrac" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "siunitx" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "mhchem" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "fontenc" t))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "multirow" t))
```

After updating my system I noticed latex images weren't being rendered. Investigating in `/tmp`, I discovered that `mhchem` wanted me to specify it's version number.

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! mhchem error: "options/no-version"
! 
! You did not specify a 'version' option for the mhchem package. Please write
! \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} in your preamble (or any lower number for
! compatibility mode).
! 
! See the mhchem documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................  

l.2971   }

? 
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................  

l.2971   }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
| 
| Try typing <return> to proceed.
| If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
|...............................................
```

By educated guess and trial and error, I determined I needed to put `version=3` in the first set of quotations. I was wondering if this was documented anywhere?

Comment: You know you can just add this to the Org file header, right? `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}`. But there is almost certainly a way of specifying the version the way you originally intended too, but I wouldn't know it off top of my head.

Comment: Actually, I tried to explain in the question that I had figured it out.  I just need to make it `'("version=3" "mhchem" t)`.  What I was looking for was documentation for this as I don't remember where I found that I could do this in the first place.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now. Well, I guess you can say its documented. If you look at `C-h v org-latex-packages-alist`, you'll see it says "options" when it describes what goes into that variable.

Comment: You do realize that you can just write `(setq org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "color" t) ("" "physics" t)...))`? And that you can simply use [Customize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) to set the complete value? And that as a general rule you *should* use Customize (or the `custom*` functions), not `setq`, to set user options?

Comment: @Drew In the past I've found `customize` to be more trouble than it's worth, especially if using version control to keep track of your configuration. Has this changed?

Comment: Dunno what you mean. If you don't want to use the Customize UI, then use the `custom-*` and `customize-*` functions in your init file. Such functions, like the UI, take all of the parts of a `defcustom` into account, including `:set`, `:type`, and `:initialize`. This means that they take care of type-checking and properly initializing and applying update (`:set`) triggers. When you use just `setq` you are out in the jungle with just a pocketknife.

Comment: @wvxvw You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @itsjeyd sorry, took me a while to reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the relevant info from the documentation of `org-latex-packages-alist` (you can view it by pressing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `org-latex-packages-alist`.

> `org-latex-packages-alist` is a variable defined in `org.el`.
>
> Its value is `(("AUTO" "inputenc" t))`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> Documentation: Alist of packages to be inserted in every LaTeX header.
>
> These will be inserted after `org-latex-default-packages-alist`. Each
>   element is either a cell or a string.
>
> A cell is of the format:
>
> ```
> ("options" "package" SNIPPET-FLAG)
> ```
>
> `SNIPPET-FLAG`, when non-nil, indicates that this package is also needed
>   when turning LaTeX snippets into images for inclusion into non-LaTeX
>   output.
>
> A string will be inserted as-is in the header of the document.
>
> Make sure that you only list packages here which:
>
> - you want in every file;
> - do not conflict with the setup in `org-format-latex-header`;
> - do not conflict with the default packages in
>     `org-latex-default-packages-alist`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

The `option` place in the cell is where the `version=3` should go in your case.